# Why are Inkscape default extensions not working?

Tags: 2d, vector-graphics, inkscape

[After perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP4Gx.png)

[Before perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jsT0.png)

[Correct perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yJBg.png)

I am using Inkscape v. 1.0. Here when I am using the perspective extension, it is not likely worked and you see the image after perspective in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jsT0.png). Actually, the correct perspective is [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yJBg.png). How can I fix this?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Please reply to the questions of the bug triage team in the bug tracker to get it fixed (and to find a suggestion about how to fix it for your case).

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/-/issues/226

For further bug reports, make sure to subscribe, so you will get email notifications.